# What happens when a checked exception propagates within a transaction?

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

I know that the default rollback policy within the Transaction Manager is automatic rolling back when RuntimeExceptions occur. Though, what happens if I have a checked exception that is allowed to propagate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However, please note that the Spring Framework's transaction
>   infrastructure code will, by default, only mark a transaction for
>   rollback in the case of runtime, unchecked exceptions; that is, when
>   the thrown exception is an instance or subclass of RuntimeException.
>   (Errors will also - by default - result in a rollback.) Checked
>   exceptions that are thrown from a transactional method will not result
>   in the transaction being rolled back.

[Source](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/transaction.html)

Even if checked exception is thrown, Spring will commit the transaction as if everything is fine.
If required you can configure a rollback on a checked exceptions.
Like

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
  <tx:attributes>
     <tx:method name="get*" read-only="false" rollback-for="AnyCheckedException"/>
     <tx:method name="*"/>
  </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

Will perform a rollback when `AnyCheckedException` is thrown.

This might help : [Spring transaction management with checked and unchecked exception](https://javasight.wordpress.com/2009/02/17/understanding-spring-transaction-management-with-checked-and-unchecked-exceptions/)

Comment: Any reason behind this choise ?

Comment: it really is a very odd choice as a default.